# AWS API Gateway ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway

One of the things that drives me nuts is that AWS has loads of docs about the format of an ARN, but doesn't have any kind of generator to make you confident that the ARN is correct.

In IAM, I'm trying to set up a policy to allow access to an API Gateway and I've read the following docs about it:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html#api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-apigateway
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.arn.html

But I can't get any ARN to validate, even just a wide open API Gateway ARN. See screenshot:

[image: open arn called invalid]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want to give full access you have to keep the ARN "*" And for all other you have to mention region or it will not work. And that ":::" will definitely not work

Comment: So you're saying `arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2::*` ? Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: I just realized you are using "AMAzon API Gateway" in service so you cannot use "apigateway" you have to use "execute-api". "apigateway" is for "Manage API Gateway"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html#api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies): *To create an IAM policy using the Policy Generator in the IAM console, select Manage Amazon API Gateway as AWS Service to set permissions statements for apigateway and select Amazon API Gateway as AWS Service to set permission statements for execute-api.*

If you are creating a policy to manage creating/editing your API, then you will need to select **Manage - Amazon API Gateway** and then use ***** to give permission for all resources. If you want to give permissions for specific resources, then use this format: (note that the service name is **apigateway**)

`arn:aws:apigateway:region::resource-path-specifier`.

If you are creating a policy to manage invoking your API, then you will need to select **Amazon API Gateway** and then use ***** to give permission for all resources. If you want to give permissions for specific resources, then use this format: (note that the service name is **execute-api**)

`arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/HTTP-VERB/resource-path-specifier`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I really wish AWS just has a tool to see the resources you have in AWS and generate an ARN. It's always one of the most annoying things about setting up AWS resources.

Comment: @Miles:  Building on this answer and to hopefully addressing your "wish" :  it looks to me like navigating to a specific resource and HTTP verb on a gateway will allow you to see that full ARN within the "Method Request" box. I have a very resource defined at `GET /v1/greetings` and the tail end of the URN, is `GET/v1/greetings`

Comment: Btw- what if you need to manage the api keys although you would like the access to only allow for retrieval of a single api key (arn:aws:apigateway:region::/apikeys/*) as opposed to many (arn:aws:apigateway:region::/apikeys)... I have noticed that this does not work... how can this be achieved ?